# Does an exponent exist that satisfies $1+3*1.2^\alpha=4*1.15^\alpha$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am considering the following problem: I am trying to prove whether or not there exists a number $\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<1$ so that

$$1+3*1.2^\alpha=4*1.15^\alpha.$$

My approach thus far: I have rewritten the equation as
$1.2^\alpha=(4*1.15^\alpha-1)/3$, and noted that the two are equal when $\alpha=0,1$.  Moreover, the derivative of the function (in $\alpha$) on the left hand side (LHS) is $1.2^\alpha ln(1.2)$ while that of the right hand side (RHS) is $1.15^\alpha ln(1.15)*4/3$.  On one hand, $ln(1.15)*4/3>ln(1.2)$, but on the other hand, $1.15^\alpha<1.2^\alpha$.  Intuitively, it appears that for small $\alpha \approx 0$, the first of these two inequalities dominates since $1.15^\alpha \approx 1.2^\alpha \approx 1$, implying that the RHS function is growing relatively faster than the LHS function, so the RHS function exceeds the LHS by an increasing amount.

However, for large $\alpha \approx 1$, I gather the second inequality would dominate, implying that the RHS is growing relatively slower than the LHS function, so the RHS function exceeds the LHS by a lesser amount until they would converge again at $\alpha=1$.  In this regard, I take that there is no such $\alpha \in (0,1)$ that satisfies the original equation.  However, I am looking for some help to formalize this intuition.

Alternatively, I welcome completely different approaches that would manipulate the original equation otherwise.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=3\times1.2^\alpha-4\times1.15^\alpha+1$ and find relative maxima/minima over $\alpha\in(0,1)$.  Then use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Here's a graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/92oecgmb5r

Comment: Oops, I see this is labeled pre-calculus, so showing the graph is concave on $(0,1)$ is out.